# How can I reset my spawnpoint and spawn back at worldspawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I set up a player spawnpoint using the `/spawnpoint` command. Now I just want to return to spawning at the world spawn.

Is this at all possible? I've tried `/kill` and I just keep spawning at my player spawn.

Comment: I am not sure this is possible from within the game and I can't test this right now. Try sleeping in a bed and destroying it, then kill yourself. If that doesn't work: Do you have access to the server files, specifically your `<player>.dat`?

Comment: From Gamepedia: "The bed is in no way tied to a player's spawn point - the game only checks for the presence of a bed at a player's spawn point when the respawn button is clicked from the death screen."... "If a player's bed is destroyed or the bed is surrounded by solid blocks and the player dies when the player had set his spawnpoint there, a message is displayed saying Your home bed was missing or obstructed, and the player will respawn at the original spawn point." Therefore sleeping in a bed and destroying it will NOT reset your spawn point, but it will work like it did reset it.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You appear to know how to use the `/spawnpoint` command, and you appear to know the location of your world spawn (if not, you can craft a compass and find out), so what exactly is preventing you from setting your spawn point to the world spawn?

Comment: @Rainbolt not having a spawnpoint is slightly different from having a spawnpoint at world spawn

Comment: @MrLemon I was under the impression that having no spawn point and having a spawn point at world spawn are **functionally** the same. I could be wrong, but since you didn't enumerate why they are different, my original impression remains unchanged.

Comment: @Rainbolt when you *have no* spawnpoint, you spawn in a ~20x20 area centered on the worldspawn, on the highest solid block for any given xz coordinate, which is quite different from spawning at a precise set of xyz coordinates that happen to coincide with the world spawn area.

Comment: @MrLemon Alright, there is a functional difference. Now we just need to establish that it is relevant to the question. OP: Do you care about spawning in a 20x20 area instead of a 1x1 area? Or do you really just want to spawn at world spawn (like the question says)?

Comment: @Rainbolt Sorry I wasn't aware of the compass. Still new to Minecraft. I'll try that now.

Comment: @Rainbolt I don't care about a 1x1 or 20x20 area, just want to find world spawn again because I lost it. But I found it with the compass, and also with the accepted answer solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/spawnpoint` command does not have a reset functionality built in, but there are other ways of doing this.

The simplest fix is to lie in a bed to set your spawnpoint to the bed, then destroy it and kill yourself. You will get the "Your home bed was missing or obstructed" message, and your personal spawnpoint will be completely unset.

---

More technical explanation, tested with Minecraft 1.8.4 and NBTExplorer:

Using `/spawnpoint` will set 4 different NBT tags for the player: `SpawnX`, `SpawnY`, `SpawnZ` stores the coordinates, and `SpawnForced` is set to 1, which means the game will not look for a bed in the vicinity of your spawnpoint.

Lying in a bed *removes* the `SpawnForced` tag, and sets the coordinates. Next time you die, the game will look for a bed. If it is obstructed or destroyed, this will fail, at which point the game also *removes* the other three tags from your `player.dat` (or `level.dat/player` for singleplayer).

Comment: Thanks so much @MrLemon I can confirm that this method works and I am now spawning back at the worldspawn after sleeping in and destroying a bed.